# Complex combination of raster bands in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I have a TIFF file containing various bands. At the moment I am using SLD to assign red/green/blue channels to bands. I would like to be able to perform more complex combinations on those bands, eg add 2 bands and assign it to the RED channel for instance.

Is this currently possible with Geoserver?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is the StyledLayerDescriptor param : 
[geoserverdocs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/sld.html) 
Here is an example : `<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"><NamedLayer><Name>worksapce:layername</Name><UserStyle><FeatureTypeStyle><Rule><Name>rule1</Name><RasterSymbolizer><ChannelSelection><RedChannel><SourceChannelName>8</SourceChannelName></RedChannel><GreenChannel><SourceChannelName>7</SourceChannelName></GreenChannel><BlueChannel><SourceChannelName>6</SourceChannelName></BlueChannel></ChannelSelection></RasterSymbolizer></Rule></FeatureTypeStyle></UserStyle></NamedLayer></StyledLayerDescriptor>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I am currently using but I need to do more complex things like red -> band 0 + band 1 / 2, for instance.